# RecyclerView in Android Studio shows some empty lists along with the required lists. The recycler view should display all available audio in the phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> I am trying to make a musicplayer project in Android Studio. I used RecyclerView to display all the audio files present in the phone with a music icon along with the song's name as an item. The problem is the output on certain devices change in the sense that the recycler view shows empty lists with only the music icon on the screen(that are not playable) and upon scrolling, the audio files present in the phone are displayed in the successive lists with the empty lists still at the top. Why are the empty lists displayed and that too only on some devices?

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SongsAdapter.SongsViewHolder.OnSongListener {

    List<Songs> songs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Dexter.withContext(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {

                        songs= Songs.getSongs(getApplicationContext());

                        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                        SongsAdapter songsAdapter = new SongsAdapter(songs,MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(songsAdapter);



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                })
                .check();

    }


    @Override
    public void onSongClick(int position) {
        Songs currentSong = songs.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlaySongsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("SongName",currentSong.getSongName());
        intent.putExtra("Uri",currentSong.getUri());
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Custom Adapter for recycler view - SongsAdapter.java**

```
    public class SongsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SongsAdapter.SongsViewHolder>{
    private final List<Songs> allSongs;
    private  SongsViewHolder.OnSongListener mOnSongListener;
    Context context;
    public SongsAdapter(List<Songs> allSongs, Context context, SongsViewHolder.OnSongListener songListener)
    {
        this.allSongs = allSongs;
        this.context = context;
        this.mOnSongListener = songListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SongsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View listItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.songs_list,parent,false);
        return new SongsViewHolder(listItem,mOnSongListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SongsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Songs currentSong = allSongs.get(position);
        holder.audio_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.music_icon);
        holder.songName.setText(currentSong.getSongName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return allSongs.size();
    }

    public static class SongsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView songName;
        public ImageView audio_image;
        OnSongListener onSongListener;

        public SongsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnSongListener onSongListener) {

            super(itemView);
            this.audio_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_image);
            this.songName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_name);
            this.onSongListener = onSongListener;
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onSongListener.onSongClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }

        public interface OnSongListener
        {
             void onSongClick(int position);
        }
    }
}
```

**To retrieve the audios present in the phone - Songs.java**

```
    public class Songs {
    private final Uri uri;
    private final String songName;

    public Songs(Uri uri, String songName) {
        this.uri = uri;
        this.songName = songName;

    }

    //Method to get all the audio files from the device
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public static List<Songs> getSongs(Context context) {

        List<Songs> songsList = new ArrayList<Songs>();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri externalContentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,

        };

        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
                externalContentUri, // Uri
                projection, // Projection
                null, // Selection
                null, // Selection args
                sortOrder // Sor order
        );



        if(!cursor.moveToFirst())   //No music files are present
        {
            //Create an alertDialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()));

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

        else
        {
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);

            while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String song_name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);


                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

                songsList.add(new Songs(contentUri, song_name));
            }
        }

        return songsList;
    }

    public String getSongName() { return this.songName; }


    public Uri getUri() {
        return this.uri;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/light_azure"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**List Items Layout - songs_list.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/items_layout"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/audio_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="audio Icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/song_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you try these modifications your lists will display properly, first add this method to your adapter:

```
public void updateSongs(List<Songs> newSongsList) {
this.allSongs = newSongsList;
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then in the main activity:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SongsAdapter.SongsViewHolder.OnSongListener {

    List<Songs> songs;
    //keep reference to your adapter here, instantiate in onCreate()
    SongsAdapter songsAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
      //instantiate adapter with an empty list, update when you have data
                        songsAdapter = new SongsAdapter(Collections.emptyList(),MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(songsAdapter);

        Dexter.withContext(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {

                        songs= Songs.getSongs(getApplicationContext());
                        //now just update your list
                        songsAdapter.updateSongs(songs);
                  

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                })
                .check();

    }


    @Override
    public void onSongClick(int position) {
        Songs currentSong = songs.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlaySongsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("SongName",currentSong.getSongName());
        intent.putExtra("Uri",currentSong.getUri());
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do these changes mean?

Comment: You want to create the adapter only once per activity, so outside of your permissions request function that is returning your list of songs.  The update songs function ensures that when you do get new lists of songs, you replace the adapters current/existing list with your new list, and notify it that its data set has changed (so that the old data is not shown after the update, only your new list).